# Laravel : How to Create Dropdown to Select FOREIGN KEY from Other Table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to ask you how to select FOREIGN KEY (from "doa_id in "doas" table) when user create a new data (to the "notes table) in a form. This is my code :

**NoteController.php**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('note/create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    Note::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'detail' => $request->detail,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'mood_id' => $request->mood_id,
        'doa_id' => $request->doa_id,
    ]);
    return redirect('notes');
}
```

**2021_05_28_020438_create_notes_table.php** *migration*

```
class CreateNotesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('note_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->date('created_at');
            $table->date('updated_at');
            $table->text('detail');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            //mood FK
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('mood_id');
            $table->foreign('mood_id')->references('mood_id')->on('moods');
            //doa FK
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('doa_id');
            $table->foreign('doa_id')->references('doa_id')->on('doas');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('notes');
    }
}
```

**and this is my dropdown html** :

```
    <div class="container">
        <label class="form-label text-white" style="font-weight: bold;" for="doa">Doa terkait</label>
        <select class="form-select" style="color: #41A7A5" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected>Pilih doa</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

[image]

In Dropdown option, I want to show "doa_name" based on it's "doa_id"

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the logic in the NoteController and the view. For example, to get a collection of all options for the foreign key, pass the collection to the view.

```
public function create()
{
    $doas =  Doas::all();

    return view('note/create', compact('doas'));
}
```

Then on the view, you can perform a `foreach` loop using the `select` HTML tag.

```
<div class="container">
    <label class="form-label text-white" style="font-weight: bold;" for="doa">Doa terkait</label>
    <select class="form-select" style="color: #41A7A5" aria-label="Default select example">
        @foreach ($doas as $doa)
            <option value="{{$doa-id>}}">{{$doa->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

After this, it's just using the input in your `store()` method.